# Mongodb $near query scanning most of my collection anyway

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial, database-performance

I have a *pois* collection with 10K documents.

And I perform the following query:

```
db.pois.find({ location: { $near: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 8.969423677143416, 45.9998108142721 ] } } }, status: "enabled", category_ids: { $in: [ ObjectId('56056db896b23c29e2000001') ] } }).skip(0).limit(1000)
```

Since I have this compound index:

```
 {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "location" : "2dsphere",
        "status" : 1,
        "category_ids" : 1,
        "properties.property_id" : 1,
        "properties.value" : 1
    },
    "name" : "location_2dsphere_status_1_category_ids_1_properties.property_id_1_properties.value_1",
    "ns" : "poi_database_production.pois",
    "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
  }
```

I was expecting better performance.

Using explain('executionStats'), I see that the index is being used, but the keys examined are ~5K; is this the number of scanned documents?

**But I have only 1K pois associated to the given category_id**, so why examine 5K keys?

The complete output of explain is [in this pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/xqycQTfG).

I was expecting mongo to use the index in oder to restrict the documents based on status and category, then use the geospatial part to fetch the 1K closest pois.

Why am I getting  such a scan? Is this the normal behavior?

Comment: Fairly normal, considering. Notably you are talking about "within a category_id" that you don't seem to be attempting to filter on in the query. If there are things that cut down results then add them to the query. MongoDB also "puports" to be reasonable about index order of fields, but I would consider it good practice still to implement the compound index fields in the most commonly used order, and order of what is likely to filter down results the most. Doing so will reduce scans. Also note that geospatial queries notoriously misreport scanned items

Comment: @BlakesSeven I had copypasted the wrong query; I updated my question. You mentioned that geospatial queries misreport scanned items, that's not nice to hear...